# Connect Ring.co doorbell to Loxone controller

Tags: relay, wiring

I've a ring.com doorbell which can be connected as shown in the diagram on the right.

My goal would be to replace the chime in that diagram by something that can replace the push button in the left diagram.

What would that "something" be?

I hope the above makes some sense, I've only a basic electronics knowledge.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be possible to connect the coil of a suitable relay (Ring suggest bell power supply can be from 8v to 24v) across the terminals of the chime (the same terminals where the diode shown is connected. Then take a 24v line from the Loxone to the Common of the relay and return from the Normally Open Contact to a Digital Input on the Miniserver. When the Ring doorbell is activated, the relay should energise and you will have an electrically isolated digital input to the Loxone. No worries.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to simply connect the wires connected to the pushbutton in the left diagram across the two screw terminals on the right diagram. No diode is necessary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feoNZj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Because there is a diode across the terminals in the right diagram, it suggests this device is using a transistor internally instead of a direct connection to the mechanical button that the user pushes. Since the diode is there to protect the transistor from damage due to driving an inductive load, it will not be necessary in your application as the microcontroller is not an inductive load.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to get something working based on the above electronics.

To solve the issue, I've created some software that is able to poll the status of the Ring doorbell and trigger anything upon detecting a ding.

The code can be found on Github: https://github.com/jeroenmoors/php-ring-api